# Discuss the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty(\ln{n})^{-\ln(\ln{n})}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Discuss the convergence or divergence of the series where the general term $x_n$ is given by

$$x_n=(\ln{n})^{-\ln(\ln{n})},\,\,n\ge 2.$$

Comment: Cauchy's Condensation Test gives you a clearly divergent series (its general term doesn't even converge to zero...)

Comment: I have not learnt Cauchy Condensation Test. Can you tell me how it works? Thanks

Comment: Google it, @anonymous....:)

Comment: @DonAntonio: Are you saying $x_n \not \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: @Henry No, he's saying $2^k\cdot x_{2^k} \not\to 0$. (Or maybe replace the $2$ with a different base, the condensation test isn't tied to $2$.)

Answer (score 10):

We have that
$$
(\ln n)^{-\ln \ln n}=\mathrm{e}^{-(\ln \ln n)^2}>\mathrm{e}^{-\ln n}=\frac{1}{n},
$$
for $n$ sufficiently large since
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\ln \ln n)^2}{\ln n}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{(\ln N)^2}{N}=0.
$$
Hence the series
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty(\ln n)^{-\ln \ln n}
$$
diverges to infinity, by virtue of the comparison test.